# Passing Programmatically props to a Component Object

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

Is that possible to add programmatically a prop to an existing React Component.

Example :

```
// GenericComp
class GenericComp extends Component {
  render = () => <Fragment>{this.props.content ? this.props.content : null}</Fragment>
}

export { GenericComp }

// AnotherFile
import { GenericComp }

// Is that possible to pass content without creating a new class like the // below :
class NewComp extends Component {
  render = () => <GenericComp content={myContent} />
}
```

Can I do something like this ?

```
const myProps = { content: 'ABCDEF' }
const enhanced = compose(GenericContent, myProps)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understanding your question properly, What do you mean by this `compose(GenericContent, myProps)`

Is that what are you trying to accomplish?

[image: Edit react-google-maps example]

**Main App**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GenericComp from './GenericComp';


const myProps = { text: 'ABCDEF' }

class Main extends Component {
  render = () => <GenericComp content={myProps} />
}

export default Main
```

**GenericCop.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class GenericComp extends Component {
  render = () => <div> {this.props.content ? this.props.content.text : null}</div>
}

export default GenericComp
```

Comment: I meant not having to use a new class to pass the props, it's possible using an HOC pattern, I did it there : https://github.com/dbrrt/yassig/blob/master/config/utils.js , this way instead of creating a new class for each case, I can just use composeMD to pass new props